# Loopback: Accessing headers from operational hooks

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I would like to access http headers in the `beforeSave` hook. The reason is because I have a field `"createdBy"` of the instance that I would like to populate with a header field.

For instance, if my header is `"Source: Client123"`, I would write something like:

```
Model.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.instance.createdBy = // something that provides "Client123"
}
```

I'm using loopback's default `"create"` method so it seems like the hook is the best way to go, unless there are any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

in server.js add the following code:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next){
  var headers = req.headers;
  app.set('headers', headers);

  next();
});
```

And in before save hook operation call it:

```
Model.observe('before save', function(ctx, next) {
   var headers = Model.app.get('headers') || {};    
   ctx.instance.createdBy = headers.createdBy;    
}
```